# Padding in select boxes

Tags: css, padding, html-select

I know select boxes are a bit of a pain to style with css, but without resorting to advanced techniques is there anyway I can add some padding to push down the text a bit without it also adding padding to the arrow on the right hand side?

Comment: Could you maybe try altering the padding on the nested 'option' elements? Just a thought...

Comment: No, there isn't.  Styling on select boxes is as you mentioned a pain.  There are many jQuery plugins for select boxes available for this very reason.  The available cross-browser styling of a listbox is very limited.

Comment: Is this not what you are hoping for? http://jsfiddle.net/LpvDg/

Comment: Nope, I only need the padding for the displayed option, not any in the dropdown list.
@Wasbazi That's what I did, but as you can see it also pads the arrow on the right.

Comment: just add font size and padding normally, then add a max-height property, to make select box being height as other imput fields. Usually only firefox needs max-height because it is slighly higher then other browsers

Answer (score 22):

add this to your CSS class. Maybe this helps?

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
```

Comment: See my answer below for how to add back a caret arrow

Answer (score 4):

Since `select` boxes appear differently on different browsers and especially operating systems, you cannot guarantee a consistency.

For example, the minimal amount of formatting I can do on a mac is this:

```
select { height:40px; background:transparent; }
```

And it looks like this:

[image: Select Box]

Comment: so do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I would recommend a custom select box, for example: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Answer (score 4):

@Demilio's answer is great for hiding the default selectbox. With custom styling you can then change the appearance of the selectbox as you wish.

The only remaining problem is the arrows/caret which are also gone, as mentioned by @romainnm.

Unfortunately pseudo elements (e.g. :after) don't work on a select element, so the only way around it is to create an actual element after the select, something like `<div class="Caret"></div>`.

Add some stylying:

```
.Caret {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

And this should result in a custom styled select box with arrows:

[image]

Unfortunately the only downside is clicking on the arrow won't open the selectbox, and that also doesn't appear to be possible to tackle with JavaScript.

Comment: You could use `pointer-events: none;` to also open the select box on click on the icon.

Comment: This is good, but maybe the best solution is using a background for the select element that shows the caret/arrow

Answer (score 1):

Interesting test here
http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3

The author covered the arrow on the right hand side and created its own, using vendor prefixed css to target different browsers. after doing that, your padding is all free.

Comment: ok .. i deserved those downvotes. its not my code. its interesting though, and it *is* a pure css solution that will work in 90% of the cases.

Comment: @HadrienTOMA - no its not ? but, I would NOT take this approach in 2020.

Comment: Thanks for coming back, I have the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused' in /var/www/cssdeck.com/app/modules/labs/models/PastebinM.php:281 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/cssdeck.com/app/modules/labs/models/PastebinM.php(281): MongoClient->__construct() #1 /var/www/cssdeck.com/app/modules/labs/controllers/HomeC.php(52): PastebinM->get('styling-select-...') #2 [internal function]: HomeC->index('styling-select-...')...

Comment: sounds like a problem with the cssdeck website (https://cssdeck.com/) .. its not my code and not my site :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use border to add padding to your select element and outline for adding the border itself

```css
.select {
    border: 12px solid #FFF;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
```

taking that you have a white background, this will work as 12px padding but it also adds padding to the arrow

Answer (score 0):

```
select {
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-position-x: 97%;
}
```