# Apply CSS to individual DropDownlist Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to apply/change CSS of an asp.net dropdown list. The code I am using is as follow:

```
for (int i =0;i < aDropdownList.Items.Count ;i++ )
{ 
   aDropdownList.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "color:Red" );
}
```

This code changes the `color` attribute just fine, but when I want to add indentation (`padding-left` or `margin-left`) it doesn't work.

```
for (int i =0;i < aDropdownList.Items.Count ;i++ )
{ 
   aDropdownList.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "padding: 0 0 0 5px" );
}
```

All I want to do is to show a nested list (a treeview like structure).

Comment: See in debug bar it change attribute of that dropdown or not?

Comment: @user1889838 - as far I know you can't do it without javascript. Discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10178233/690329).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using space? Here is one implementation - http://blog.phoenixdigital.com/?p=331